# How to prove " $¬\forall x P(x)$

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I have a step but can't figure out the rest. I have been trying to understand for hours and the slides don't help. I know that since I have "not P" that there is a case where not All(x) has P... but how do I show this logically?

1. $\forall x (P(x) → Q(x))$         Given
2. $¬Q(x)$             Given
3. $¬P(x)$             Modus Tollens using (1) and (2)
4.
5.
6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you want to instantiate your quantified statement with a witness, say $x$: 
So from $(1)$ we get $$\;P(x) \rightarrow Q(x) \tag{$1\dagger$}$$
Then from $(1\dagger)$ with $(2)$ $\lnot Q(x)$, by modus tollens, you can correctly  infer $(3)$: $\lnot P(x)$.

So, from $(3)$ you can affirm the existence of an $x$ such that $\lnot P(x)$ holds: $\quad\exists x \lnot P(x)$

Then recall that, by DeMorgan's for quantifiers,$$\underbrace{\exists x \lnot P(x) \quad \equiv \quad \lnot \forall x P(x)}_{\text{these statements are equivalent}}$$

Comment: Still cranking I see! :-) +1

Comment: Oh so you are just using Instantiation to be able to apply MT then since I found the !P which I found before, you use Existential Generalization to go back to {\exists} and then use another rule to go back to the (all ) X? Sounds so easy but is difficult to follow rules for going back and forth.

Comment: Yes, that's essentially it! Existentially generalize $\exists x\lnot P(x)$, then this is logically equivalent to $\lnot\forall xP(x)$

Comment: There are a number of ways one can prove your statement, but the route we're using is arguably most efficient. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: I am still learning and proofs are by far the hardest. This may be a stupid question, but is the last step just Demorgan's law? Like an Inverse of the solution?

Comment: I'm so stupid, I just looked at the DeMorgan's laws for negating quantifiers and that's exactly what it is. Just thought I'd share. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Nicely dramatized Amy.

Comment: Thanks, @Babak ! How are you today?

Comment: Waking up $\longrightarrow$ Correcting the papers $\longrightarrow$ Breakfasting $\longrightarrow$ Again papers. :-(

Comment: @Babak Oh, goodness! (You forgot "$\longrightarrow$ and checking in on math.se!") ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Oh yes dear. The page is open on front my eyes while doing the job. And, I couldn't get a big fish yesterday at the site Amy.

Comment: **Revision:** Or you could **assume $\forall x~P(x)$** then derive a contradiction using Universal Instantiation (twice) and Modus Ponens. Thereby deducing $\neg\forall x~P(x)$ via a *proof of negation*.$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~\forall x~(P(x)\to Q(x))\\~~2.~\neg Q(x)}{\fitch{~~3.~\forall x~P(x)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Assume}}{~~4.~P(x)\to Q(x)\hspace{4.5ex}\textsf{UI (1)}\\~~5.~P(x)\hspace{13ex}\textsf{UI (3)}\\~~6.~Q(x)\hspace{13ex}\textsf{MP (4,5)}\\~~7.~\bot\hspace{16ex}\textsf{C! (2,6)}}\\~~8.~\neg\forall x~P(x)\hspace{10ex}}$$